# Can't restart apache due to invalid 'echo' command

Tags: sudo, apache2, restart

When i enter command

```
admin@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
[sudo] password for admin:
```

I get this msg

```
Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn:
Invalid command 'echo', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

Please tell me how i restart my apache2 server...

Comment: Did you already try "apache2ctl restart" (without quotation marks)?

Comment: You first need to fix the syntax error in file `/etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn`. Please edit your question and include that file if you need help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have a syntax error in a config file.  The first step would be to look at `/etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn` to see what it says, and perhaps post the contents of the file if you need help.  You can check this file with a text editor, or use `cat` or `less` (ie `gedit /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn`).

FYI, this file stands for "Fully Qualified Domain Name", and is normally a single line with something like this:

```
ServerName localhost
```

That should be all that is necessary for a home server.  Did you change this file?

Comment: contents of the fqdn file is:ServerName localhost

echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn